# What percentage of RAM can I allocate as heap

Tags: linux, memory, java

I have 32 GB RAM on host, where I need to run java program ( On JRE 1.7 64 Bit).

Currently I have specified 8 GB as heap memory. I am wondering how much can I increase ? I just run the java webapp on that host.

Comment: How much does the java application need? Also, what on earth are you doing that requires 8GB of memory?

Comment: Thats what I want to figure out. It is used by one of the critical system used by people worldwide :)

Comment: You've provided no information on what the application does. How much heap does it usually use? Is it running out of memory? Are there other applications on the system? Do they have enough memory? Is disk cache important? The only answer that can be provided with the current information is "Between 0% and 100%"

Comment: You can allocate as much as you want between virtually nothing or all of your physical memory.  This sounds like a problem that would require the source code, the specific section of code your asking about, which means its a Stackoverflow question.  The current question is extremely broad and sort of low quality if we take your question literally as "how much of the system memory can I allocate to the heap?"  the answer to that question is a single word **"all"**

Comment: How do you know you need more heap?  You don't need more unless you're getting out of memory errors or GC is running *really really* frequently.

Comment: If you really want to know what the optimal size is for your JVM heap, you need to use the available performance tools to collect execution statistics and analyze them.

Comment: You don't allocate "RAM" for heap. The heap allocation you specify for the Java VM is virtual memory. The OS's memory manager decides how much of that gets kept in RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Heap is not allocated from RAM. It's allocated from virtual address space. You can even have more heap than you have RAM. Much more. The Java VM has no direct access to physical addresses (RAM addresses) and is not limited by them, any more than is any other process in your system.

Comment: However, if you don't NEED the larger heap, making it larger than available RAM will cause the JVM to run *slower* (perhaps *much* slower).

Comment: No, not really. Virtual memory allocated stays "vapor" until it's first referenced. If the JVM doesn't access the unneeded virtual address space, it never gets faulted into RAM, so it can't cause anything else to get paged out.

Comment: But if you make heap larger than RAM then virtual memory begins to "thrash" as it swaps back and forth to disk.  Execution speed drops by a factor of 10-100.

Comment: (Understand that if you make heap large, the JVM will tend to use that space, even though it could have easily used GC to constrain to a smaller size.)

Comment: Ah, you're talking about lack of GC. Suppose in my code I allocate a buffer, use it for a while,then "free" it. By not GCing it it tends not to be used again for future allocs. BUT! If my code doesn't reference it again (as it should not for a freed region), it doesn't matter if it's paged out for lack of access. I agree there is some cost, but thrashing only happens if you're actually accessing all of the v.a.s.

Comment: The problem is that if you create a large heap then it, in effect, becomes sparsely allocated -- a few objects with lots of empty space in-between.  This inflates the virtual memory with "noise" -- the "working set" for the heap becomes larger than RAM and thrashing results.

Comment: (Understand that in Java you don't "free" anything.  It gets collected when it gets collected.)

Comment: (And on most systems a "page" is 4K, so you can have one 64-byte "live" object and 3-something K of "dead" objects on a single page.  The "live" objects don't get packed together until GC runs (if then).)

Comment: Re lack of "free": Sure, but objects are freed when they go out of scope, or when you otherwise lose "interest" in them. ¶ I'm not saying there's no cost to making the heap huge. Just that there's no hard limit re. RAM size (as was claimed), and that there is no _automatic_ sudden page thrashing just because you have a large heap - it all depends on access patterns. Nor is a large heap the only thing that can cause page thrashing. ¶ I have a Java app that needs a lot more heap allocated than one would think, just to keep the GC from running all the time... life is full of tradeoffs.

Comment: The net-net is that making the heap unnecessarily large is a performance drag, and making it larger than available RAM is a BIG performance drag.  I've been working with virtual memory since 1972 and with Java for 17 years, including 10 of those years helping to maintain a JVM which was for several years the fastest JVM in the world.  I kinda know what I'm talking about.